# FTP cannot access virtual folder

Tags: iis, ftp

I've created a virtual folder for a folder residing at C:\Documents and Settings\..\Data

Remote users are able to see the base folder of the FTP site, but are unable to see the Virtual folder. Is sharing a folder in the  path forbidden?

-zeekial

Answer (score 0):

If you use ADS server means you can create virtual directory by setting Username,Password in ADS and you can access in remote place through ftp with created username,Password.

or

If you don't have ADS means you can change the Default FTP site Directory path manually, and you can access it from remote place. please find the attached screen shot.

[link text](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/9996/ftpip.jpg)